# PHP count total files in directory AND subdirectory function

Tags: php, file, count, directory

I need to get a total count of JPG files within a specified directory, including ALL it's subdirectories. No sub-sub directories.

Structure looks like this :

```
dir1/
2 files  
   subdir 1/
       8 files
```

total **dir1** = 10 files

```
dir2/ 
    5 files  
    subdir 1/ 
        2 files  
    subdir 2/ 
        8 files
```

total **dir2** = 15 files

I have this function, which doesn't work fine as it only counts files in the last subdirectory, and total is 2x more than the actual amount of files. *(will output 80 if I have 40 files in the last subdir)*

```
public function count_files($path) { 
global $file_count;

$file_count = 0;
$dir = opendir($path);

if (!$dir) return -1;
while ($file = readdir($dir)) :
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
    if (is_dir($path . $file)) :
        $file_count += $this->count_files($path . "/" . $file);
    else :
        $file_count++;
    endif;
endwhile;

closedir($dir);
return $file_count;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the fun of it I've whipped this together:

```
class FileFinder
{
    private $onFound;

    private function __construct($path, $onFound, $maxDepth)
    {
        // onFound gets called at every file found
        $this->onFound = $onFound;
        // start iterating immediately
        $this->iterate($path, $maxDepth);
    }

    private function iterate($path, $maxDepth)
    {
        $d = opendir($path);
        while ($e = readdir($d)) {
            // skip the special folders
            if ($e == '.' || $e == '..') { continue; }
            $absPath = "$path/$e";
            if (is_dir($absPath)) {
                // check $maxDepth first before entering next recursion
                if ($maxDepth != 0) {
                    // reduce maximum depth for next iteration
                    $this->iterate($absPath, $maxDepth - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // regular file found, call the found handler
                call_user_func_array($this->onFound, array($absPath));
            }
        }
        closedir($d);
    }

    // helper function to instantiate one finder object
    // return value is not very important though, because all methods are private
    public static function find($path, $onFound, $maxDepth = 0)
    {
        return new self($path, $onFound, $maxDepth);
    }
}

// start finding files (maximum depth is one folder down) 
$count = $bytes = 0;
FileFinder::find('.', function($file) use (&$count, &$bytes) {
    // the closure updates count and bytes so far
    ++$count;
    $bytes += filesize($file);
}, 1);

echo "Nr files: $count; bytes used: $bytes\n";
```

You pass the base path, found handler and maximum directory depth (-1 to disable). The found handler is a function you define outside, it gets passed the path name relative from the path given in the `find()` function.

Hope it makes sense and helps you :)

Answer (score 11):

You could do it like this using the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

```
<?php
function scan_dir($path){
    $ite=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);

    $bytestotal=0;
    $nbfiles=0;
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ite) as $filename=>$cur) {
        $filesize=$cur->getSize();
        $bytestotal+=$filesize;
        $nbfiles++;
        $files[] = $filename;
    }

    $bytestotal=number_format($bytestotal);

    return array('total_files'=>$nbfiles,'total_size'=>$bytestotal,'files'=>$files);
}

$files = scan_dir('./');

echo "Total: {$files['total_files']} files, {$files['total_size']} bytes\n";
//Total: 1195 files, 357,374,878 bytes 
?>
```

Comment: @Neoweiter this scans sub-sub directories too, I thought you specifically wanted only up to sub-dir level?

Comment: @jack, I won't use sub sub dirs, but if the script looks for it it's not so important ;)

Comment: You can use the [`setMaxDepth()`](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator.setmaxdepth) method on the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to limit the depth of recursion: here you probably want to set it as `1` (i.e, one sub-directory deep).

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone awesome just what I needed thanks. One more number of folders in the array will give it 100 on 100 :)

Comment: it includes hidden shortcut link like double dot .., and dot.

Comment: You can add something for is_dir(), so that the directories are not counted in the files.:)

Comment: To remove dot file (not directory). Change to:
$ite = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

Answer (score 1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function printTabs($level)
{
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    $l = 0;
    for (; $l < $level; $l++)
        echo ".";
}

function printFileCount($dirName, $init)
{
    $fileCount = 0;
    $st        = strrpos($dirName, "/");
    printTabs($init);
    echo substr($dirName, $st);

    $dHandle   = opendir($dirName);
    while (false !== ($subEntity = readdir($dHandle)))
    {
        if ($subEntity == "." || $subEntity == "..")
            continue;
        if (is_file($dirName . '/' . $subEntity))
        {
            $fileCount++;
        }
        else //if(is_dir($dirName.'/'.$subEntity))
        {
            printFileCount($dirName . '/' . $subEntity, $init + 1);
        }
    }
    printTabs($init);
    echo($fileCount . " files");

    return;
}

printFileCount("/var/www", 0);
```

Just checked, it's working. But the alignment of results is bad,logic works

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Developer is actually brilliant!
Use it like this to make it work:

System("find . -type f -print | wc -l");

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is looking to count total number of files and directories.

Show/count total dir and sub dir count

```
find . -type d -print | wc -l
```

Show/count total number of files in main and sub dir

```
find . -type f -print | wc -l
```

Show/count only files from current dir (no sub dir)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | wc -l
```

Show/count total directories and files in current dir (no sub dir)

```
ls -1 | wc -l
```

Comment: Down voted since that is by no means answering the question

Answer (score -3):

A for each loops could do the trick more quickly ;-)

As I remember, opendir is derivated from the SplFileObject class which is a RecursiveIterator , Traversable , Iterator , SeekableIterator  class, so, you don't need a while loops if you use the SPL standard PHP Library to retrive the whole images count even on subdirectory.

But, it's been a while that I didn't used PHP so I might made a mistake.